# Difference between 黒齣 and 黒駒

Tags: translation, homophonic-kanji

I'm trying to figure out if there's a difference in meaning/translation between

> 黒齣

and

> 黒駒

[image: image of unknown character]

I've attached an image just to make sure that I didn't accidently look up the wrong character (I'm 99% sure it's the correct one but still).

**A bit of context:** both show up on black background. There is no further context to be given.

The first one I've seen translated as **black scene**, which makes sense because according to [this](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%BD%A3), **齣** can mean either *frame* or *scene* in this context.

For the second one, the translation was also **black scene** but I'm not entirely sure if it's indeed correct. I think I found the correct character ([here](http://www.edrdg.org/cgi-bin/wwwjdic/wwwjdic?1MMJ%E9%A7%92) and [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%A7%92)), but translations like *horse* or *shogi piece* just don't make any sense to me.

I have the feeling they both mean the same, but I just want to make sure.

Comment: Both of them are words Japanese speakers almost never use, and you have concealed everything needed to get the right meaning. If this is a screenshot of a game, what's the name of it? What do you mean by "static frames/scene"? How is this word used? Is this a part of a longer sentence, or is this the only word in that "frame"? Where did the kanji 齣 come from?

Comment: This reminds me of sesame seeds

Comment: ^ 黒ゴマ ww　------

Comment: 「黒齣」はどうも化物語のアニメに出てくるようですね

Comment: @naruto It's just a screenshot. That's it. If there was more context to it, I would have given it already. *It's just this single frame showing up for several seconds* (it shouldn't matter which game/animation). Not used in a sentence, just those two characters on a black screen. "How is the word used?" - I don't know for sure, I think to display that it's a black scene/frame. "Is this a part of a longer sentence, or..." - It's just the two characters on a black screen, I cropped it to fit more easily here. "Where did the kanji 齣 come from?" - it's on the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it shouldn't matter which game/animation

Yes it does matter. Even native Japanese speakers cannot explain the interpretation of such a rare word without knowing where you saw it.

黒齣 is not a regular word. As @broccoliforest suggests, googling it points to one specific anime called 化物語. I checked the [first episode](https://www.b-ch.com/titles/2774/001), and found that it heavily uses flashing typograms of seemingly random archaic words. 黒齣 is one of them. Meaning-wise, it should mean "a frame filled with black", but I don't know if it's a real word or a made-up word of Akiyuki Shindo. Either way, I bet you won't see this word again outside this anime.

Regarding 黒駒, it's not an ordinary word, either. If you saw it in a work related to 化物語, it's natural to assume it's just a typo for 黒齣. 齣 is a fairly rare kanji, so it is no wonder if someone mixed it with 駒.

Comment: I didn't know it was such a "rare" occurence (I'll take back that "...it shouldn't matter" then). Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

駒 and 齣 are both pronounced こま in kun'yomi. Despite appearing similar and being pronounced the same they are two different kanji and carry two different meanings. 齣 is an uncommon kanji (as stated in the Wiktionary page you referenced).

> 黒駒 means 'black horse'. It can be either a description of such or a place name. An additional meaning of 駒 is 'chess piece').
>
> ---
>
> 黒齣 means 'black frame/cut', part of a film where the screen is black (blank) and reveals information, usually in numeric form, about the film.